# Rails basic index view with haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm trying to get a basic index view to work using HAML instead of HTML, but I'm running into problems.

Here is my index view

```
%h1 
    Games
%ul
    - @games.each do |game|
    %li
        = game.title
        = game.summary
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
```

But I know haml doesn't require you to have `end` when you embed ruby on the view, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be very careful with indentation in `haml`. You need to indent what's inside the `each`

```
- @games.each do |game|
  %li
    = game.title
    = game.summary
```

I would also suggest sticking to 2 spaces as that is pretty much accepted practice in Ruby/Rails.